# Awaiting function that resolves a promise with no arguments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have a function that resolves a Promise without passing any arguments:

```
const checkUser = (user)=> {
    let promise = Parse.Promise();

    if(user.success){
        promise.resolve();
    } else {
        promise.reject("Error");
    }
}
```

The problem is that in all tutorials that I read, they assign the returning value to a variable, like this:

```
let response = await checkUser(user);
```

In the above case, can I just await for the promise without assigning the result to a variable or this is not recommended? For example:

```
...
await checkUser(user);
...
```

Comment: I think the asignment is not obligatory since you may for example do operation which is not returning anything for example a wait implementation.

Comment: Yes you can if you don't matter the result, and you will may use `try { await } catch (e) { ... }` syntax to check error thrown by reject function

Comment: You never have to assign the result of an expression to something else. `await ...` is an expression, just like `foo()` or `1 + 1` are .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can totally do that. JavaScript will still wait for the promise to resolve.

Here is a modification of [MDN's first example for `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#Examples). It does not return a value but still waits for the Promise to resolve before running the code after `await`.

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() { 
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  });
}

(async function() {
  console.log(1)
  await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(2);
})()
```

Comment: That could be simplified to `return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))` or if the ESnext proposal for partial application was implemented, you could even do `return new Promise(setTimeout(?, 2000))`. The `?` turns the function call into a partial application that looks like `x => setTimeout(x, 2000)`

Comment: Yes, but it's really not about the function, this just shows that you can await without setting a variable. If you feel the code your proposed is easier to understand, edit my answer...

Answer (score -1):

I think it is a bad practice to resolve a promise with nothing, as that's the appropriate channel for results. And if you don't want to get a result, why would you have called a function at all? This might apply to functional programming mostly, though.

> Can I just `await` the promise without assigning the result to a variable or this is not recommended?

Yes, you can totally do that. If you don't need to do anything with the result - like when you know that it always is `undefined` - then you can just ignore it.

Comment: I think an example use-case would be waiting for a database write transaction to complete. You already know the data you're sending and all you need to know is whether the promise was resolved or rejected in that case. I wouldn't go as far as to say it's "bad practice" but it should raise the question of whether in fact it is necessary, as you said. Also, obligatory "I didn't downvote"